# How to fetch data from infinite scrolling webpage using BeautifulSoup and Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get all the article links under "https://uynaa.wordpress.com/category/%d0%be%d1%80%d1%87%d1%83%d1%83%d0%bb%d0%b3%d1%8b%d0%bd-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%bb%d1%8d%d0%bb/". The problem was that my code couldn't get all the articles under the link because it was scrollable. I found this package called selenium, however still using selenium, my code does not find all the articles.

```
import os
import requests
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./chromedriver")
browser.get("https://uynaa.wordpress.com/category/%d0%be%d1%80%d1%87%d1%83%d1%83%d0%bb%d0%b3%d1%8b%d0%bd-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%    bb%d1%8d%d0%bb/")

body = browser.find_element_by_tag_name("body")

no_of_pagedowns = 20

while no_of_pagedowns:
    body.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
    no_of_pagedowns-=1


html = urlopen("https://uynaa.wordpress.com/category/%d0%be%d1%80%d1%87%d1%83%d1%83%d0%bb%d0%b3%d1%8b%d0%bd-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%bb%d1%8d%d0%bb/").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")


for element in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'blog'}):
    for link in element.findAll('h2'):
        for alink in link.findAll('a'):
            try:
                print (alink['href'])
            except KeyError:
                pass
```

How do I get all the article links under this URL?

Answer (score 2):

There is a function in selenium to scroll down the site. Then just wait a few seconds with e.g. time.sleep(2) and then you can scrape the content of the next div tags. Just put this in a Loop and it should work.